# netzke FormPanel

Tags: extjs, netzke

I think i stucked here. I have a model (Test) with 3 fields: id, name, name2. So  i want to write there something and click on Apply button on bottom and if all fields are filled and passed validation (i guess this i should do in model Test.rb, yeah?) and get to localhost:3000/some/where and if i left some filed (name or name2) unfilled so i get a message  like "ERROR".

test_panel.rb

```
class TestPanel < Netzke::Basepack::FormPanel


    js_mixin :actions


    def configuration
        super.merge(
            :name           => :test_panel,
            :model          => 'Test',
            :title          => "TEST PANEL",
        )
    end

end
```

action.js

```
{
  onApply: function() {
        var form = this.getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
              this.Apply(form.getFieldValues(), function(success) { 
                    if (success) {
        window.location = 'some/where';
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.show({ 
                     title: 'FF', 
                     msg: 'I guess you have an error!!', 
                     buttons: Ext.Msg.OK, 
                     icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING }); 
            }
          }, this);
        } else { 
                     Ext.Msg.show({ 
                     title: 'FF', 
                     msg: 'Fill all fields!!', 
                     buttons: Ext.Msg.OK, 
                     icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING }); 
                 }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to show error message from Rails? if it all you want you should create an endpoint by yourself and set flash message then return {:netzkeFeedback => @flash}

Comment: Which version of Netzke do you use? Also, in earlier versions of Netzke it heavily lied on names of components. So I suggest you do not set names of panels and other non-field controls.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct no need to do any thing with netzke. Just write your validators in the rails model. If any field is failed to pass the validation Netzke will capture the validation message from rails model and display it on top of the grid.